# can i send a JDIALOG behind a JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jlayeredpane

I am experimenting `JLayeredPane` to work on some issue
.
But I am not able to get one result.

Is there any way that I can use a `JLayeredPane` on my `frame` and a `JDialog` that pops up goes behind `JLayeredPane` instead of coming in front.

It is possible??

Comment: Show the code you use to add the dialog to the `JLayeredPane`, and we may be able to help - as is, we don't know what you tried (e.g. `add(dialog, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER)`?)

Comment: `Is there any way that I can use a JLayeredPane on my frame and a JDialog that pops up goes behind JLayeredPane instead of coming in front.` no. A JDialog is a Window and windows can't be added to a layered pane (or any Component).

Comment: @camickr then why do we have POPUP_LAYER variable in JLayeredPane

Comment: Read the tutorial on [The Layered Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#layeredpane). A popup is like a JPopupMenu, not a JDialog.